# Cloud flare block PHP CURL request NOT IP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am using PHP curl for a year, but now it has stopped working.
I have confirmed that my IP is not blocked but when I scrape through curl I get error **"Sorry, you have been blocked"**

I have tried `file_get_content` and guzzle library, but same response.

Need a solution to scrape data

CODE:

```
$URL = 'https://www.example.com'; //working
$URL = 'https://www.widgets.investing.com/live-currency-cross-rates?pairs=1,2,3,4,5,6,1128748';
$res1 = simple($URL);
$res2 = method_one($URL);
$res3 = method_cookie($URL);


var_dump($res1);
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($res2);
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($res3);
```

Method try 1

```
function simple($URL){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Method try 2

```
function method_one($URL){
    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
        'accept: */*',
        'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $result =  curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);  
    echo 'content type: ' . $info['content_type'] . '<br />';
    echo 'http code: ' . $info['http_code'] . '<br />';

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Method try 3

```
function method_cookie($URL){
 $ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
        'accept: */*',
        'accept-encoding: gzip',
        'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,  fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");

$result =  curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);  
echo 'content type: ' . $info['content_type'] . '<br />';
echo 'http code: ' . $info['http_code'] . '<br />';

curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
}
```

RESPONSE

[image]

__
My ip is not blocked, i try on 3 new servers, and get same error, i try 3 different internet network provider, and get same error. Link is working by direct browser access

Comment: You could contact the owner of the site and ask them if you can use their data.

Comment: I am able to access `www.widgets.investing.com....` using CURL perfectly well soo it is your curl implementation that is not correct. You have no configuration options to deal with the SSL connection for instance & I'm curious why you send the XMLHttpRequest header

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius headers such as that one and a falsified user agent string are common ways to make automated traffic look more legit / more like a regular desktop webbrowser's requests. Still, in the arms race with security software packages on the other side, it's not a panacea.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius can you please share your Curl code?

Answer (score 0):

The curl function and code I used to successfully send a GET request to the url specified in the question. The config is such that any url using SSL is treated appropriately by selecting the `cacert.pem` file to verify the certificate

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    /*
        Download a copy of CACERT.pem from
        https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
        
        save to webserver and modify the $cacert variable
        to suit - ensuring that the path you choose is
        readable.
    */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem'; # change this path...


    session_write_close();

    /* Initialise curl request object - these should be OK as-is */
    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, $cacert );
    }

    /* Define standard options */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.38' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
    
    /* enhanced debug */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
    

    /* Assign runtime parameters as options to override defaults if needed. */
    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }
    /* send any headers with the request that are needed */
    if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }

    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'status'    =>  curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}


$url='https://www.widgets.investing.com/live-currency-cross-rates?pairs=1,2,3,4,5,6,1128748';
$res=curl( $url );

if( $res->status==200 ){
    echo $res->response;
}
```

Comment: I download the https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem FILE, and place it in D, and change the path in code, and investing.com return 403 response but other URLs are working, i try it on local and on VPS and on 4 different IPS. getting same error,

Comment: 403 is Forbidden - analyse the full output response, especially the `verbose` property as that will contain useful info